# Arrange plots in a layout which cannot be achieved by 'par(mfrow ='

Tags: r, graphics

I have three plots which I would to arrange in a single window. I can arrange similar-sized plots on a regular 2*2 grid using `par(mfrow = c(2, 2))`:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot(1:10, main = "plot1")
plot(10:1, main = "plot2")
plot(rnorm(10), main = "plot3")
```

However, I want to position "plot1" and "plot2" beside each other on the top row, and "plot3" below them, centered horizontally. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean @Marco. You ask for the third graphic to lie in between the first and third graphics. This is surely a typo as how can something be positioned between itself and something else ;-) Can you clarify what you mean? Perhaps show us a figure and tell us where on that figure you want the graphics - e.g. `png("my_plot.png"0); layout(matrix(1:4), ncol = 2)); for(i in 1:4) { plot(1:10) }; layout(1); dev.off()` and insert that figure into your Q and tell us exactly where you want your three figures?

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: The question is now edited, thx!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably want `layout`, you can set up pretty complex grids by creating a matrix.

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 0, 1,  3, 2, 3, 2, 0), nrow = 2, ncol = 4)
##set up the plot
layout(m)
## now put out the 3 plots to each layout "panel"
plot(1:10, main = "plot1")
plot(10:1, main = "plot2")
plot(rnorm(10), main = "plot3")
```

Use `layout.show` to see each panel.

Print out the matrix to see how this works:

```
 m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    1    2    2
 [2,]    0    3    3    0
```

There are 1s for the first panel, 2s for the second, etc. 0s for the "non-panel".

See `help(layout)`.

Comment: Yes, this is one possibility. But still, is it possible to have 2 rows and 2 columns? By the way, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: you'll need to clarify further, but I think I know what you want now - layout

Comment: Ah yes, a quite clever usage of `layout` ! (clever in the sense of "but why, oh why, didn't I thought of it myself !") :-)

Answer (score 17):

Not exactly what you are asking for, as the third figure is not horizontally centered but stretched to the full device width, but the `layout` function allows for a much more flexible configuration.

For example, the following layout definition :

```
R> layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
R> plot(rnorm(100),col=1)
R> plot(rnorm(100),col=2)
R> plot(rnorm(100),col=3)
```

Gives the following result :

[image: layout with horizontal third figure]

You can also use a "vertical" stretch with the following layout :

```
R> layout(matrix(c(1,3,2,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
R> plot(rnorm(100),col=1)
R> plot(rnorm(100),col=2)
R> plot(rnorm(100),col=3)
```

Which gives :

[image: layout with a vetrtical third figure]

Another workaround is to save your figure as a pdf and edit it with a tool like inscape to "center" your third figure.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am sure I will use it later!