# print odd number of multiple plots per page

Tags: r, plot

I know that the following can be used to print 6 plots per page:

`par(mfrow = c(3, 2))  # 3 rows and 2 columns`

However, I only need 5 plots per page. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can use `layout` for more control

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244014/arrange-plots-in-a-layout-which-cannot-be-acheived-by-parmfrow might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `layout` to plot only five charts. The `matrix` part shows where to plot which chart. The `0` means "do not plot a chart in this part".

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,0), 3, 2, byrow = TRUE))
plot(1:10)
plot(1:10)
plot(1:10)
plot(1:10)
plot(1:10)
```

[image]